# How can I embed website in React website?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have complete single page website based on legacy technologies. Website use jQuery and many others scripts and files. I would like to somehow embed this whole website (including scripts) in React component. I can make redirect to this page but I want to authorize user by React. Is it possible? Some hints? It can be hard to rewrite all scripts

I tried insert whole code into:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '...'}} />
```

but scripts are not launched

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can use `<iframe>`: https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe